# Setting up an online discord bot

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, discord, discord.js

Quite a loaded question but Ill try to be as specific as possible.

My goal is to have my bot running online for it to communicate between a database and multiple discord servers. Quite simply how would you go about implementing such a feature into a bot and what is the process of hosting such a bot?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you add what discord library you're using as tags

Comment: Is there an specific way to connect a database to discord bot? Why don't you just use discord.js, your database and axios to do your job? https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/#installing-and-using-sequelize

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple database, I would recommend using quick.db https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db
As for hosting, I personally use Heroku but there are obviously more options depending on your needs. Amazon AWS would also be a good hosting place for your bot too.